# NAS recommendation

Tags: command-line, nas, afp

I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a 4-bay NAS with AFP/TimeMachine support and the ability for me to install `s3cmd` (a utility for simple S3 syncing).

The reason I ask is simple: just having a back up at home isn't good enough. I've used Dropbox for a while now but since we've got a number of machines my ultimate aim is to back them up to a NAS and for that NAS to sync with S3 a few times a day so we'd have a remote version.

Comment: Hardware shopping questions are off topic. If you wanted to edit this to be about how to evaluate any NAS for compatibility with `s3cmd` at might be fine to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synology has a [few solutions](http://www.synology.com/products/index.php?lang=enu). Their products are reliable and affordable.

There are multiple applications you can install in a few clicks but for S3 backups you will have to go the [manual way](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_backup_the_Synology_Server_to_Amazon_S3).

Comment: I second this advice. I have one (single bay) and I'm very happy with it. I also backup offsite on S3 but manually.